# using variable number of arguments in a function call and delegating them to another function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have got a global function which has the following signature:

```
void Systemfehlerprotokollieren(BYTE quelle,WORD fehlercode,WORD subfehlercode,
    BYTE klassifizierung, BYTE status,BYTE kanalnummer,DWORD detailfehler,
    WORD modulnummer,WORD location,WORD wLenZusatzText,char *pcZusatztext);
```

This function I want to simplify in two ways.

1. Use variable arguments like in printf instead of `pcZusatztext`
2. And thus get rid of parameter `wLenZusatzText`
3. Use the original signature in a local context

So my external function (the last parameters) would look like:

`ext_Systemfehlerprotokollieren(WORD location, char *form, ...);`

this function then should call `void Systemfehlerprotokollieren(. . . )` with its above mentioned parameters as before.

Right now I have the following code parts:

```
void vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(BYTE quelle,WORD fehlercode,WORD subfehlercode,
    BYTE klassifizierung,BYTE status,BYTE kanalnummer,DWORD detailfehler,
    WORD modulnummer,WORD location,va_list args)
{
    int ret;
    char zepuf_printf_mode_lokal[ZELE];
    memset(&zepuf_printf_mode_lokal[0],0x00,ZELE);
    ret = vsnprintf_s(zepuf_printf_mode_lokal, ZELE-1,_TRUNCATE, "%s",args );
    if (ret != -1)
    {
        if (ret < 0)
        { 
            Systemfehlerprotokollieren(quelle,fehlercode,subfehlercode,
               klassifizierung,status,kanalnummer,detailfehler,
               modulnummer,location,0,NULL);
            return;
        }
    }
    Systemfehlerprotokollieren(quelle,fehlercode,subfehlercode,
        klassifizierung,status,kanalnummer,detailfehler,
        modulnummer,location,strlen(zepuf_printf_mode_lokal),zepuf_printf_mode_lokal);
}
```

in above function `Systemfehlerprotokollieren` will be called as usual

and

```
void SystemFehlerKG(WORD wFehlerCode, WORD wSubFehlerCode,BYTE KanalNummer,
    DWORD detailinfo2, DWORD detailinfo3, WORD programmstelle, char *form, ... )
{
    va_list args = NULL ;
    if (form != NULL)
    {
        va_start(args, form);
        vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(SYS_FEHL_QUELLE_FLEXOS,wFehlerCode,wSubFehlerCode, 
            SYS_FEHL_KLASS_FEHLER, SYS_FEHL_STATUS_FEHLER_KOMMT_GEHT, KanalNummer, 
            (WORD)detailinfo2, (WORD)detailinfo3, programmstelle,args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    else 
        vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(SYS_FEHL_QUELLE_FLEXOS,wFehlerCode,wSubFehlerCode, 
            SYS_FEHL_KLASS_FEHLER, SYS_FEHL_STATUS_FEHLER_KOMMT_GEHT, KanalNummer, 
            (WORD)detailinfo2, (WORD)detailinfo3, programmstelle,"");
}
```

This works fine, when i call the second function like this:

```
SystemFehlerKG(5000+TCPIP_SYS_ERROR_FKT_SEND,0,SYS_FEHL_KANAL_ALLG,
    iRet,0,SFPROG_00000,"%s","");
```

but I don't know what to change to get the same result with

```
SystemFehlerKG(5000+TCPIP_SYS_ERROR_FKT_SEND,0,SYS_FEHL_KANAL_ALLG,
    iRet,0,SFPROG_00000);
```

... where the last two parameters are omitted...

[Edit #1]:

I see, that `printf();` doesn't work either, it must be at least `printf("");`

so the closest possible approach would be

```
SystemFehlerKG(5000+TCPIP_SYS_ERROR_FKT_SEND,0,SYS_FEHL_KANAL_ALLG,
    iRet,0,SFPROG_00000,"");
```

[Edit #2 as suggested by @Jan Krüger]:

```
void SystemFehlerKG(WORD wFehlerCode, WORD wSubFehlerCode,
    BYTE KanalNummer, DWORD detailinfo2, DWORD detailinfo3, 
    WORD programmstelle, char *form, ... )
{
    va_list args = NULL ;
    va_start(args, form);
    vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(SYS_FEHL_QUELLE_FLEXOS,wFehlerCode,
        wSubFehlerCode, SYS_FEHL_KLASS_FEHLER,
        SYS_FEHL_STATUS_FEHLER_KOMMT_GEHT, KanalNummer, 
        (WORD)detailinfo2, (WORD)detailinfo3, programmstelle,args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

I dont have the code at hand right now, but i think, that this threw an exception when `form` was not a valid (format) string (being NULL or "").

I will tell tomorrow.

[Edit #3:]

I made the changes to my code as in edit#2. Did not work.
But I found the error:

`void vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(BYTE quelle,WORD fehlercode,WORD subfehlercode,
    BYTE klassifizierung,BYTE status,BYTE kanalnummer,DWORD detailfehler,
    WORD modulnummer,WORD location,va_list args)`

needs to be

`void vSystemfehlerprotokollierenText(BYTE quelle,WORD fehlercode,WORD subfehlercode,
    BYTE klassifizierung,BYTE status,BYTE kanalnummer,DWORD detailfehler,
    WORD modulnummer,WORD location,char * form, va_list args)`

the function `SystemfehlerKG`has to be changed also to reflect the parameter `form`.

One thing still isnt very clear to me:
If I am using the `...` in my top most function and want to call another function that uses the `...` signature, what must i be aware of?

Comment: Change language? C doesn't allow for optional parameters. You have to supply all parameters before hyphens (ie `SystemFehlerKG(5000+TCPIP_SYS_ERROR_FKT_SEND,0,SYS_FEHL_KANAL_ALLG,iRet,0,SFPROG_00000, "");`, or `SystemFehlerKG(5000+TCPIP_SYS_ERROR_FKT_SEND,0,SYS_FEHL_KANAL_ALLG,iRet,0,SFPROG_00000, NULL);` if `NULL` is allowed for `char *form`).

Comment: It depends on how the function works. If documentation says that a `NULL` in format is considered as no other argument is ok. `printf` use the format string to print base text (i.e. `printf("hello!\n");`) and also to check if there are other arguments. So format **must be not null**.

Comment: I cannot change language, it must be C, because its part of a greater project written in plain C.

Comment: I cant get what you wanted to say with your second comment...??

Comment: What I ment is already well expressed in Jan Kruger answer in reference to `printf`. But if you are writing your own function you could have something like: `if (format != NULL) { ... //use variadic part}` checking the value allows you to work or not on the variadic part. `printf` assumes that format always point to memory that can be read, assigning NULL to it will result in a memory access error. In any case the last parameter before the hyphens is a standard parameter and you can't omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is well-spotted. In `printf` and friends, the format string is not part of the variadic part of the function's signature. You have to pass it separately as a normal argument.

The other important bit: you *always* have to pass on the `va_list` structure to `vsnprintf_s` (via your `vSystemfehlerprotokollieren`), even if you're sure there are no extra arguments. So, don't make the `va_start` and `va_end` conditional.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth to answer your final question about calling `...` functions from `...` functions, I believe the simple answer is: you can't. At least not if you want to pass on the variadic arguments. As I said, this is the reason stuff like `vprintf` exists in the first place... it's the only way to pass on your variadic args to printf. Of course, if you're not actually trying to pass your variadic args (e.g. calling `printf` with unrelated arguments), there's nothing special to consider.